# LetsEncrypt using cloudflare server ssl error

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

Recently I discover letsencrypt which is awesome project, and it basically allows you to get ssl certificate for free.

I manage to setup my server and domain with their certificate, everything work great and my site showed the https in green which was great.

Then I connected this domain to cloudflare, which is another great solution, for many web problems.

Once my name servers were changed to cloudflare name servers the https stopped working.
:(

Comment: Note that the certificate expires after 90 days and thus needs to be renewed each 90 days.

Comment: Thanks I know that and already setup many reminders to renew withing 3 month. (:

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what is the root of that issue, but I manage to fixed it with a little bit of luck, so decided to write here the problem and the solution who worked for me in case other will encounter this issue in the future.

On cloudflare
https://www.cloudflare.com/a/crypto/yourdomain

default settings for ssl is full, once I changed it to
**strict** https start working again like charm.

---

2 days after I had the same issue, I changed it back to **full** from **strict** and then it worked again so I am confused and not sure if my answer here is good.

Answer (score 1):

you  need to use certbot when you're already using cloudflare.

check this [link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-get-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-while-using-cloudflare/6338)

So before you run the certbot command try this first export LC_ALL="C"

Then if you're on apache change the command to this

./certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html/ --renew-by-default --email email@host.tld --text --agree-tos -d example.tld -d www.example.tld

/var/www/html/ = where your webroot path for the domain is located.

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue that CloudFlare said there is a 526 error.
I could solve it by adding
`SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/chain.pem"`
to the apache hosts config, since Apache < 2.4.8 needs the chain (see http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html)